# Image memory issues in iphone retina display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, retina-display

I am developing a game for a company. Right now we are coming across a problem.
Our game is made for the iphone and ipad. We have both regular images and @2x images. Our game works perfectly fine on iphone 3gs and all the ipad versions. But our game crashes on iphone 4 and 4s.
Is it crashing because its retina? I know all the images are 4x.
We are now wondering what kind of ways it can crash.

Can anyone help me out here?

### EDIT:

our game uses `UIKit`, `cocos2d` and uses `OpenGL`

Comment: Did you see any error message? Did it crash in simulator? Please describe the situation in detail.

Comment: it does not see any error messages, it just crashes.

Comment: it does not crash on the simulator

Comment: This really isn't enough information for us to track down the problem.  Try and create a new project, with 1 image and 1 image view in it.  Test it on all the same devices and see what happens. If the problem is reproduceable, edit some code into the question.  If it's not, consider what else you might be doing to cause the issue.

Comment: Does the device console (in the organizer) show anything?

Answer (score 0):

How do you load images into imageviews? if you use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"blablabla.png"]` - that's evil - [look here why](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/). Use this instead:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/name_of_image.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]].
```

ALWAYS.

EDIT: adjust the above image name to include @2x when you are loading retina sized images.

Comment: we use cocos2d for most of the images, so i dont think this is the problem

Comment: well, how much allocations do you do while using those images?

Comment: have you tested the app for memory leaks in Profiler?

Comment: we always release after we are done using them. we did profile it, but it shouldnt crash after playing it for 20 seconds

Comment: if you would see the link I gave you, you knew that releasing an image object allocated using "imageNamed", does not actually free all the memory. And when you have a plenty of images, you are "phacked".

Comment: all our images calls from uikit, we use imagewithcontentsoffile

Answer (score 0):

So do this: in Xcode uncheck all @2x images - so imageNamed will only find the normal images. Run the app. does it crash? If so then its not the images. Now start turning on the @2x images - a few at at time. Run it. does it crash?

If you have a slew of @2x retina images for retina iPad, yea, might be a problem. You don't say how many images you are using - if hundreds yeah, don't use imageName. I use a small amount and have no problems iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Do it from the build phase pane in the project settings. Filter by @2x and just remove everything.

Comment: Right do it by hand one at a time or do a script. Script may take you just as long but u can then reuse it later.